# Password authentication fails when connecting to database through python psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, postgresql-10

I am trying to connect to my local postgres database through a python jupyter notebook. I am using psycopg2 which seems to be installed correctly.

I just created a user called 'username' with the password 'my_pw'. I did that directly in the PG Admin query window:

```
CREATE USER username
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE my_db TO username;
ALTER USER username WITH PASSWORD 'my_pw';
```

My connection code looks like this:

```
import psycopg2 as p

conn = p.connect("host='localhost' dbname='my_db' user='username' password='my_pw'")
```

When i run it i get this error message:

```
OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username"
```

Would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

Allow this user into **pg_hba.conf** configuration file.

[For more info](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Answer (score 0):

grant user to access unix socket on pg_hba conf like this

```sh
local   all             postgres                                md5
local   all             <some user> # <- user registered here   md5
```

if you use Linux operating system edit file on `/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf`